# boostrap badge animate with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

Take a look at Bootstrap's Badges: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges

I need to make a class that animates the badge inside the glyphicon something like this:

```
<div class="notification-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
        <span class="badge">19</span>
    </div>
```

Then the badge animation on first page load show color red could hop if possible then fades off onmouse hover or onclick.
I got color red by doing something like this:

```
<div class="notification-icon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
            <span class="badge alert-danger">19</span>
        </div>
```

but it doesn't hop just yet neither fade off onmouseover or onclick after 5 minus(milliseconds) similar on stackoverflow account login...

Comment: Where is your js?? and please make a fiddle and replicate problem.

Comment: Please if I could do the js I wouldn't be asking, Be KIND..